# Getting 'Infinity' output instead of actual numbers

Tags: java, math, infinity

I am practicing some Java and one of the applications I am writing asks to output the world population in the next 75 years.

I am using the population growth model. My issue is that my application outputs 'Infinity' in the column where the estimated population should be output.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class WorldPopulationGrowth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double currentWorldPopulation = 7.4e9;
        double worldPopulationGrowthRate = 1.13;
        double anticipatedWorldPopulation;
        int initialYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

        System.out.println("Year\tAnticipated World Population (in billions)\tPopulation " +
                "increase since last year");
        System.out.println(String.format("%d\t%.1e\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNA", initialYear, currentWorldPopulation) );


        for(int i=1; i < 76; i++){
            int year = initialYear + i;
            double growthExponential = worldPopulationGrowthRate*year*1.0;
            anticipatedWorldPopulation =  currentWorldPopulation * Math.pow(Math.E, growthExponential);

            System.out.println(String.format("%d\t%.1e\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", year, anticipatedWorldPopulation));

            currentWorldPopulation = anticipatedWorldPopulation;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging through it? Your `growthExponential` is being multiplied by the current year, for each iteration, which will definitely throw off your math

Comment: You also seem to be doing other incorrect things with your math by using `Math.E` which by itself will nearly triple `currentPopulation` each iteration, but you're raising it to a power of several thousand each time..

Comment: The growth should be by the formula `pow(GrowthRate, i)` or `exp(log(GrowthRate)*i)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a careful look at the first iteration of your code, as if we were debugging it (Make sure you try to do this in the future!)

- `currentWorldPopulation` = 7.4e9
- `worldPopulationGrowthRate` is 1.13
- `initialYear` is 2016
- your loop begins, `i` is 1

  - `year` is set to 2017
  - `growthExponential` is set to 1.13 * 2017 = 2279.21 (this is the start of your problem)
  - `anticipatedWorldPopulation` is set to 7.4e9 * e^2279.21
  - this is roughly 7.4e9 * 7.05e989... KABOOM

Revisit your calculations, and step through your application (ideally in a debugger) to see your problems.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I'd advise the OP to accept and upvote this one.  Good eye, @Krease

Comment: Thanks, got it straightened out. I was using the percentage increase as 1.13 instead of the correct 0.0113 and instead of the year, I replace year by the counter i.

Comment: And I would upvote this if I had enough reputation to be able to! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Krease found your problem.

I recoded it.  Once you fix the issue he found it's fine.  I used JDK 8 lambdas and gave you both percentage and exponential growth models.  The code prints both for comparison:

```
import java.util.function.DoubleFunction;


/**
 * Simplistic population growth model
 * @link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38805318/getting-infinity-output-instead-of-actual-numbers/38805409?noredirect=1#comment64979614_38805409
 */
public class WorldPopulationGrowth {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double currentWorldPopulation = 7.4e9;
        double worldPopulationGrowthRate = 1.13;
        int numYears = 76;
        int startYear = 1976;

        double populationExponential = currentWorldPopulation;
        ExponentialGrowthModel modelExpGrowth = new ExponentialGrowthModel(worldPopulationGrowthRate);
        double populationPercentage = currentWorldPopulation;
        PercentageGrowthModel modelPercentGrowth = new PercentageGrowthModel(worldPopulationGrowthRate);

        System.out.println(String.format("%10s %20.3e %20.3e", startYear, currentWorldPopulation, currentWorldPopulation));
        for (int i = 1; i < numYears; ++i) {
            populationExponential = modelExpGrowth.apply(populationExponential);
            populationPercentage = modelPercentGrowth.apply(populationPercentage);
            System.out.println(String.format("%10s %20.3e %20.3e", startYear+i, populationExponential, populationPercentage));
        }
    }
}

class ExponentialGrowthModel implements DoubleFunction<Double> {

    private double exponent;

    ExponentialGrowthModel(double exponent) {
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }

    private double getExponent() {
        return exponent;
    }

    public void setExponent(double exponent) {
        this.exponent = exponent;
    }

    @Override
    public Double apply(double value) {
        return value*Math.exp(this.getExponent());
    }
}

class PercentageGrowthModel implements DoubleFunction<Double> {

    private double percentageIncrease;

    PercentageGrowthModel(double percentageIncrease) {
        this.percentageIncrease = percentageIncrease;
    }

    private double getPercentageIncrease() {
        return percentageIncrease;
    }

    public void setPercentageIncrease(double percentageIncrease) {
        this.percentageIncrease = percentageIncrease;
    }

    @Override
    public Double apply(double value) {
        return value*(this.getPercentageIncrease());
    }
}
```

Comment: The math is off by even more than that ;) see my comments on the question.

Comment: Now that I'm reading the code more carefully I can see that you're right.  The OP has confused a power model with an annual percentage increase for the fatal effect.